# Jetty 9 - How do I set "request content" and "request headers" using Jetty 9?

Tags: java, jetty

I used ContentExchange class of Jetty 7 for setting URL, headers and requestContent.
Following is What I have using Jetty 7.

```
    HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
    client.start();
    ContentExchange exchange = new ContentExchange();
    exchange.setURL(url);
    exchange.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/xml");
    exchange.setRequestHeader("Authorization", "Basic " + this.getAuthenticatonString());
    exchange.setMethod("POST");

    final AbstractBuffer cb = new ByteArrayBuffer(xml.getBytes("UTF-8"));
    exchange.setRequestContent(cb);

    client.send(exchange);
    exchange.waitForDone();
```

Jetty 9 doesn't have ContentExchange class but after some research I have this

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client
.POST(url)
.send()
```

I think I can use client.param for setting request headers but I am not really sure about it.

**So my question is how do I set "request content" and "request headers" using Jetty 9?**

Comment: Did anything work for you?

Comment: nope! I just kept using Jetty 7 for a while and then switched to Jersey.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.HttpClient;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.Request;
import org.eclipse.jetty.client.ContentResponse;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpMethod;
import org.eclipse.jetty.http.HttpHeader;
...
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
client.start();
Request req = client.newRequest("http://....");
req.method(HttpMethod.GET);
req.agent("Mozilla/5.0...");
req.header(HttpHeader.ACCEPT, "text/html");
req.header(HtppHeader.CONNECTION, "Keep-Alive");
ContentResponse resp = req.send():
...
client.stop();
```

Answer (score 1):

In addition to the above answer,

I was working with Jetty 11 Http Client and realized that **req.header** has been deprecated in the latest release. ( **11.0.5** ).

As a result I had to figure out a way send authentication headers with Jetty Http Client 11.

This is how I did it. Pay attention to line 4.

```
    httpClient.start();
    URI uri = UriBuilder.fromUri(URI.create(ENDPOINT)).path("v1/testPath").queryParam("testParam","testValue").build();
    InputStreamResponseListener listener = new InputStreamResponseListener(); //Required for large responses only
    httpClient.newRequest(uri).method(HttpMethod.GET).headers(httpFields -> httpFields.add("Authorization","Bearer "+token)).send(listener);
    Response response =  listener.get(20, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    if(response.getStatus() == 200){
        //doSomething.
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

If any one stumbles on documentation,

for the case of content: `req.post(OldWayOfcontentProviders)` is deprecated and replaced with : `req.body(Request.Content oneOfFollowingImplementations)`

please refer utils( `org.eclipse.jetty.client.util`) where some of the pre-defined implementations example-

`ByteBufferRequestContent`

`StringRequestContent`

`MultiPartRequestContent` ...

All of them have implementation of Request.Content Interface.

Example:

```java
      post.body(new ByteBufferRequestContent("text/xml", ByteBuffer.wrap("MyXMLContentAsString".getBytes)))
```